# Can't change position of button

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

In a C++ app I create a button using CreateWindowEx and later try to change its position using SetWindowPos, but the button doesn't appear where I want it.

What's interesting is that when I resize the window (with the mouse, not programatically), I can see for a split second a blank silhouette the same size of the button where the button is supposed to appear. This must be because I also call SetWindowPos in response to window resizing events. However the actual button stays at the same location. I'd post a screenshot but for some reason the silhouette never shows up in screenshots.

This is the code that changes the X position (the code that changes the Y position is almost identical):

```
HRESULT Control::put_Left(float left)
{
    RECT windowRect;
    ::GetWindowRect(m_hWnd, &windowRect);

    if (m_isTopLevel)
    {
        BOOL bResult = ::SetWindowPos(
            m_hWnd,
            nullptr,
            static_cast<int>(DesktopDpi::GetInstance().DipsToPixelsX(left)),
            windowRect.top,
            0,
            0,
            SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOREPOSITION
            );

        if (!bResult)
            return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(::GetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        // NOTE: for a button this is the code that will execute, because a
        // button is not a top-level window

        HWND hWndParent = ::GetParent(m_hWnd);
        if (hWndParent == nullptr)
            return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(::GetLastError());

        POINT parentPos = {0, 0};
        if (!::ClientToScreen(hWndParent, &parentPos))
            return E_FAIL;

        BOOL bResult = ::SetWindowPos(
            m_hWnd,
            nullptr,
            static_cast<int>(DesktopDpi::GetInstance().DipsToPixelsX(left)),
            windowRect.top - parentPos.y,
            0,
            0,
            SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOREPOSITION
            );

        if (!bResult)
            return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(::GetLastError());
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: Please ignore my original answer (if it's still there below) as I misread your question. If you see the button move briefly and then return to where it was, are you sure your `put_Left` function isn't being called twice? I would put some `OutputDebugString` calls in to print out the coordinates being passed to `SetWindowPos` and see exactly where the button is being positioned.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the parent of the button isn't moving it back to the old position when it handles `WM_SIZE`?  It sure sounds like it from your description.